# Posts relacionados Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, funções, wordpress-theme, plugin-wordpress

Fala galera,

estou desenvolvendo um tema wordpress, e em uma página eu uso uma função para pegar os posts relacionados, ele pega todos os posts até o atual. Porém ele não precisaria pegar o atual, qual seria a forma de excluir o post atual e mostrar realmente só os relacionados?

OBS: estou usando um custom_post_type=cursos

Valeu!!!

```
function postagem_relacionada() {

    $post_id = get_the_ID();
    $cat_ids = array();
    $categories = get_the_category( $post_id );

    if(!empty($categories) && is_wp_error($categories)):
        foreach ($categories as $category):
            array_push($cat_ids, $category->term_id);
        endforeach;
    endif;

    $current_post_type = get_post_type($post_id);
    $query_args = array( 

        'category__in'   => $cat_ids,
        'post_type'      => $current_post_type,
        'post_not_in'    => array($post_id),
        'posts_per_page'  => '10'

     );

    $related_cats_post = new WP_Query( $query_args );

    if($related_cats_post->have_posts()):
         while($related_cats_post->have_posts()): $related_cats_post->the_post(); ?>
           <div class="card text-gray height-100p shadow-v2">
              <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="<?php echo get_field('imagem_do_curso') ?>" alt="">
              </a>
              <div class="p-4">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="h6">
                  <?php the_title(); ?>
                </a>
                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-pill" style="color: #191B31!important">
                  + <?php echo get_field('quantidade_de_alunos_formados') ?> Alunos formados
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>   
        <?php endwhile;

        // Restore original Post Data
        wp_reset_postdata();
     endif;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fala parceiro, tudo beleza?

Você vai conseguir dessa forma abaixo.

No single-cursos.php do seu tema, você deve adicionar:

```
    <?php 
        $currentID = get_the_ID(); 
        query_posts( 
            array(
                'posts_per_page' => 4,
                'post_type' => 'cursos', 
                'orderby' => 'rand', 
                'post__not_in' => array($currentID) 
            ) 
        ); 
    ?>
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            // ESTRUTURA DO LOOP AQUI DENTRO
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Note que eu botei um "orderby" como sendo "rand", ou seja está pegando os posts relacionados de maneira randômica. Daí fica a seu critério.

Espero ter ajudado!

Valeu.

Answer (score 0):

Muito obrigado pela ajuda, também consegui resolve, no meu canso tinha um erro no código `'post_not_in'`, o correto é `'post__not_in'`segue o código com correção caso alguém precise:

Adicionar nos funcions.php

```
function postagem_relacionada() {

$post_id = get_the_ID();
$cat_ids = array();
$categories = get_the_category( $post_id );

if(!empty($categories) && is_wp_error($categories)):
    foreach ($categories as $category):
        array_push($cat_ids, $category->term_id);
    endforeach;
endif;

$current_post_type = get_post_type($post_id);
$query_args = array( 

    'category__in'   => $cat_ids,
    'post_type'      => $current_post_type,
    'post__not_in'    => array($post_id),
    'posts_per_page'  => '10'

 );

$related_cats_post = new WP_Query( $query_args );

if($related_cats_post->have_posts()):
     while($related_cats_post->have_posts()): $related_cats_post->the_post(); ?>
       <div class="card text-gray height-100p shadow-v2">
          <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="<?php echo get_field('imagem_do_curso') ?>" alt="">
          </a>
          <div class="p-4">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="h6">
              <?php the_title(); ?>
            </a>
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-pill" style="color: #191B31!important">
              + <?php echo get_field('quantidade_de_alunos_formados') ?> Alunos formados
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>   
    <?php endwhile;

    // Restore original Post Data
    wp_reset_postdata();
 endif;
```

}

Chamar no single.php ou single-$slug.php:

```
<?php postagem_relacionada() ?>
```

Espero que essa postagem venha a ajudar mais alguém futuramente, agradeço a todos comunidade, especialmente ao nosso amigo Brício Fernandes que se dispôs a ajudar.